# Install a TFS 2018 plugin

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2018 and I'd like to install a plugin called "Replace Tokens".
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens

Due to some restrictions in my network I cannot install it from the marketplace so I downwload it (qetza.replacetokens-3.1.0.vsix file).

I am not entire sure how to install this plugin from this file but I double clicked in the file which opened the launcher. but than I got this error:

[image]

In the log I got this:

```
15/05/2019 13:30:41 - Searching for applicable products...
15/05/2019 13:30:41 - Found installed product - Global Location
15/05/2019 13:30:41 - Found installed product - ssms
15/05/2019 13:30:41 - Found installed product - Visual Studio Community 2017

     15/05/2019 13:30:41 - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension is not installable on any currently installed products.
        at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionService.GetInstallableData(String vsixPath, 
    String extensionPackParentName, Boolean isRepairSupported, IStateData 
    stateData, IEnumerable`1& skuData)
       at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.IsExtensionPack(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.ExtensionPackService.ExpandExtensionPackToInstall(IStateData stateData, Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize(Boolean isRepairSupported)
   at VSIXInstaller.App.Initialize()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

Maybe I am not approaching this from the right angle.

Can anyone tell me how to install this plugin whithout using the Marketplace?

EDIT: I even read the Microsoft documentation but I cannot find the way to install the extension using it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions?view=azure-devops-2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You current screenshots indicate that you tried to double-click the VSIX, which tries to process it as a Visual Studio plug-in.

The instructions for TFS 2018 are here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions?view=tfs-2018#install-team-foundation-server-extensions-when-disconnected, your link was to the Azure DevOps 2019 install guide, which has a different UI for this. In general, when looking at the new docs, make sure you've selected the correct version in the top-left above the side bar.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. I download the plugin and followed the install documentation which was provided when I downloaded the plugin.